# Remove dropdown list from a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table which in each row has dropdownlists in row2. My question is how could I remove a dropdownlist if there is for example in that same row value called "Delivery" ?
Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fp67wLqz/

```js
window.onload = $('#my_id tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $ArtNo = $(this).find("td:eq(7)").html();
  if ($ArtNo == 'Delivery'){
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").empty();

  }

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

thead:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

thead tr:first-child {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  padding: 50px;
}

input button {
  display: inline;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 800px;
}

.table-responsive table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-responsive thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 2px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

.myButtons {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Filtered CSV File</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="dataframe my_class" id="my_id">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:right;">
          <th> </th>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
          <th>col5</th>
          <th>col6</th>
          <th>col7</th>
          <th>col8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>Delivery</td>
          <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I also tried with only **empty() , or html("")** but it didn't work. 
Any help would be great

**EDIT** this is how I would like it that my table looks like after it deletes the dropdown list from the second row :

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

thead:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

thead tr:first-child {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  padding: 50px;
}

input button {
  display: inline;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 800px;
}

.table-responsive table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-responsive thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 2px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

.myButtons {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="dataframe my_class" id="my_id">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:right;">
          <th> </th>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
          <th>col5</th>
          <th>col6</th>
          <th>col7</th>
          <th>col8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Delivery</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove in what sense ?

Comment: to just have empty td

Comment: On which event, page load ? or a button click ?

Comment: on a page load. since my table is created dynamically

Comment: Why td:eq(7) ?? The td that contains Delivery is 3rd td :eq(2) (first column is th).

Comment: @NawedKhan sorry I did a bad copy paste on the first html example

Comment: The column containing delivery text is unknown ?

Comment: delivery always appears in the same column

Comment: Note that your first snippet contains a syntax error. It is unclear from your question whether that is what is causing your code to fail or not. Click "Run code snippet" to see the error.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just noticed , there was missing ' -for delivery, but that is not the problem in my code. this above code is just an example. my table has over 20 columns and is created dynamically and the dropdown lists are also added dynamically. I tried adding the **if condition where "delivery" * * to skip but it is not doing that

Answer (score 1):

This achieves what you want assuming the delievery is always in the third cell of the corresponding row.

```js
window.onload = $('#my_id tbody tr').each(function() {
  var artNo = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html();
  if (artNo == 'Delivery') {
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").empty()
  }
  /*assuming you dont know in which cell delievery occurs:
  let delete = false;
  $(this).find('td').each (function() {
    let art = $(this).text()
    if(art == 'Delivery'){
      delete = true;
    }
  });
  if(delete){
  $(this).find('td').each (function() {
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").empty()
  });
  }*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="dataframe my_class" id="my_id">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:right;">
          <th> </th>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
          <th>col5</th>
          <th>col6</th>
          <th>col7</th>
          <th>col8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>Delivery</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks for help but, I already tried that , I wrote it in the question

Comment: What do you mean? My answer gives your desired output. The dropdown gets removed if the third cell in a row contains delivery.

Comment: I tried with **$(this).find("td:eq(1)").empty()** but it did nothing it didn't removed it

Comment: Copy/paste his code because yours is wrong. For exemple you omit a quote after Delivery ($ArtNo == 'Delivery), your indexes eq() are false, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) functions to get your result.

Since we know that the delivery column is the 3rd column everytime.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#my_id tbody tr').each(function(i, el) {
    const deliveryColumn = $(this).children().eq(3).html();
    if (deliveryColumn === 'Delivery') {
      $(this).children().eq(2).html('');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

thead:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

thead tr:first-child {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  padding: 50px;
}

input button {
  display: inline;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 800px;
}

.table-responsive table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-responsive thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  padding: 2px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

.myButtons {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Filtered CSV File</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="dataframe my_class" id="my_id">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:right;">
          <th> </th>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
          <th>col5</th>
          <th>col6</th>
          <th>col7</th>
          <th>col8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
          <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>Delivery</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
          <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>a</option>
              <option>BB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
          <td>row3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when I use your code to find the dropdown inside the console.log before the use of **empty()** it shows it is empty already ...that only means there is no value selected from the dropdown list

Comment: @AmilaBečirović dropdown inside the console.log ? Not sure if this solves your problem